# Compute the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}/726\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{77}]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, localization

I am computing the cardinality of the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}/726\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{77}]$. Following are my several attempts:

1. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=726\mathbb{Z}$ which is an ideal of $R$, and $M=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{77}]$. Then $(R/I) \otimes_R M \cong M/IM$ as $R$-modules. After this I can re-consider $M/IM$ as an $R/I$ module to compute the cardinality. But I got stuck since $M/IM$ is not a free $R/I$-module.
2. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\{77^n:n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\}$ is multiplicatively closed in $R$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}/726\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{77}]=S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ and $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} S^{-1}\mathbb{Z} \cong S^{-1}A$ as $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Again at this point I am stuck.
3. Treat the tensor product as usual, i.e. using the pure tensors. Actually I can prove that any elements of the tensor product can always be written as $a(\overline{1} \otimes \frac{1}{77^n})$ for some integer $a$ and some non-negative integer $n$. Again I got stuck with what to do next because the pure tensors with different $n$'s can be equal, for instance $\overline{1} \otimes \frac{1}{77}=\overline{77} \otimes \frac{1}{77^2}$ etc...

I think I got stuck because both $726$ and $77$ are not prime numbers. It makes the actual computation become more complicated. Also I guess that the possibilities for the cardinality are $726$, $77$, $11$ (the $\gcd$), $5082$ (the ${\rm lcm}$) and even infinite. However I still can not predict the structure of the tensor product, at least the most convenient form to compute the cardinality.

Any helps or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Two hints maybe. First, try using CRT and distributing the tensor product. Second, it's maybe helpful to visualise this calculation as "trying to invert 77 in M" which may help morally

Comment: Why is the first approach not working? You have $IM = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{11}]$, so pretty sure $M/IM$ should have $7$ elements.

Comment: @Jakobian Eh could you please explain why?

Comment: Okay I think I might be wrong here, but first approach still feels like the best one.

Comment: Actually $77$ and $726$ has the only common prime divisor which is $11$. Anyway thanks you two so much. I'll try again. :D

Comment: Is this a repost (under a distinct username) of [that post soon closed yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790782)?

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah that post and that account are not mine. I am trying to solve this question for several days :D Maybe it's someone in my class asked it but I never talked to him :D

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, Mystery girl.

Comment: Typically people change up the numbers when they ask a question here, so that the method demonstrated can then be used be the questioner who know (presumably) understands the method to compute with their own numbers. Why are you all posting your problem statement directly on here with the same exact parameters - it's not something particularly thoughtful to do.

Comment: @Snared Oh I didn't know this moral :( Actually I saw that post just 15 minutes ago, but it was already closed. I understand why it was closed, so I reposted it with my attempts. I think there's no problem with it because I have my own effort and thoughts about the problem...

Comment: @Snared I don't understand your comment either. Did you find any old analogous post which received an answer?

Comment: Having your own and thoughts about the problem is just one requirement of a good question. I didn't say it was wrong to post your homework problems here verbatim with thoughts, but it does make me wonder how much answering these problems is worth to the students to help their understanding versus just get them over their current roadblock associated with a particular function of their life. I just don't see why you don't generalize the problem and post it and then compute yours as a special case. It makes the student actually rewrite it - versus paraphrasing how the gold rep solves their issue

Comment: For all I know it could be an exam question after all, heck, I had to compete against exactly such kind of student while I was trying to complete take home exams with integrity during Covid. So maybe it's just a bit of a soft spot with me.

Comment: Apologies for assuming, I just think that if two people from your class post the exact question with the exact same parameters, it could be a very IMPORTANT question for them to solve, for one reason or another, and in that particular case I am keenly aware of things like schools have honor codes, and in my school's case, quite a bit of 'no outside help' on certain kinds of assignments.. Anyhow, I think it's fine to post questions, I want to encourage it, because of course it is you taking the risk and we are left to operate under the assumption solving this problem doesn't cause more harm tha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first approach works: since $726=11^2\cdot6$ and $11$ is invertible in $M,$
$$M/IM=M/6M.$$
Let us now prove that the group $M/6M$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z,$ or more generally, that
$$\gcd(m,n)=1\implies\Bbb Z[1/m]/n\Bbb Z[1/m]\cong\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$$
Consider the canonical homomorphism
$$f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z[1/m]/n\Bbb Z[1/m].$$

- Its kernel is $n\Bbb Z,$ because $f$ sends $n\Bbb Z$ to $0$ and conversely, any integer $k\in\ker f$ is such that $k=n\frac a{m^b}$ for some $a\in\Bbb Z,b\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0},$ which implies $n\mid m^bk$ and therefore $n\mid k$ (since $m^b$ and $n$ are coprime).
- $f$ is surjective, since every $\frac a{m^b}\in\Bbb Z[1/m]$ ($a\in\Bbb Z,b\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$) is equal to $c+n\frac d{m^b}$ for some $c,d\in\Bbb Z,$ i.e. $a\in m^b\Bbb Z+n\Bbb Z,$ by Bézout.

By the first isomorphism theorem, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Just a follow-up question: Could I view this question as localization of the quotient $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ at $m$? There is a name for the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $S=\{p^n:n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\}$ if $p$ is prime, but I'm not sure if we could generalize $S$ for any natural numbers.

Comment: No because in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,$ $m$ is already invertible.